# grepping with labeling

Tags: linux, grep

I have the following details from processed query:

```
queuename                      qtype resv/used/tot. np_load  arch          states
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abax55@lp55cs008               BP    0/36/36        1.08     lx-amd64      
    gf:app_monitor=1
    gf:app_abaqus=1
    gf:app_abaqusfgs=1
    gf:app_actran=1
    hl:load_avg=38.980000
    hl:load_short=38.550000
    hl:load_medium=38.980000
    hl:load_long=39.030000
```

I want to grep only `hl:load_avg=38.980000` with prefix `abax55@lp55cs008`
that means, output should look like:

```
abax55@lp55cs008 - hl:load_avg=38.980000
```

.... this is just for one machine named as `cs008`. and the total number of machines would be 100+.

Please suggest 2 options:

1. for grepping only a particular machine,
2. for grepping all machines

Comment: *grepping all machines* - what is the naming convention for all machines? do they have a common prefix in their names?

Comment: abax55@lp55cs001
abax55@lp55cs002
abax55@lp55cs003
abax55@lp55cs004....so on!

Comment: my only input for this entire querry should be 'abax55', rest everything has to be done by shell

Comment: Your question is still unclear and must it be grep? If for one case grepping is easy then print that text before the result

Comment: Using grep `rep -o "hl:load_avg=38.980000" machines | xargs -L 1 echo "abax55@lp55cs008 -"`, or awk `awk 'match($0,/hl:load_avg=38.980000/) { print "abax55@lp55cs008 - " substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }'  machines`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

1) for grepping only a particular machine:

```
awk -v m="cs008" '/abax55@lp55cs[0-9]/ && $1 ~ m{ m_name=$1 }
       m_name && /hl:load_avg=/{ print m_name" - "$1; exit }' file
```

The output:

```
abax55@lp55cs008 - hl:load_avg=38.980000
```

---

2) for grepping all machines:

```
awk '/abax55@lp55cs[0-9]/{ m_name=$1 }
     m_name && /hl:load_avg=/{ print m_name" - "$1; m_name=0 }' file
```

Comment: is it possible to run the entire command in a single line?

Comment: @Nayak, elaborate your question, it sounds vague

Comment: is it possible to 'awk -v m="cs008" '/abax55@lp55cs[0-9]/ && $1 ~ m{ m_name=$1 } awk -v m="cs008" '/abax55@lp55cs[0-9]/ && $1 ~ m{ m_name=$1 } 'in a single line ?

Comment: yes. this can be run all on one line. Replace the newlines in the quoted awk script with `;` characters.  (either or both newline and `;` can be used to separate statements in `awk`).

Comment: very much simple solution and runtime is low....thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For Testing i have inserted same content  in file multiple times by changes the hostnames in file

```
input file

queuename                      qtype resv/used/tot. np_load  arch          states
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abax55@lp55cs008               BP    0/36/36        1.08     lx-amd64
    gf:app_monitor=1
    gf:app_abaqus=1
    gf:app_abaqusfgs=1
    gf:app_actran=1
    hl:load_avg=38.980000
    hl:load_short=38.550000
    hl:load_medium=38.980000
    hl:load_long=39.030000
queuename                      qtype resv/used/tot. np_load  arch
states
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abax55@lp55cs009               BP    0/36/36        1.08     lx-amd64
    gf:app_monitor=1
    gf:app_abaqus=1
    gf:app_abaqusfgs=1
    gf:app_actran=1
    hl:load_avg=38.980000
    hl:load_short=38.550000
    hl:load_medium=38.980000
    hl:load_long=39.030000
queuename                      qtype resv/used/tot. np_load  arch
states
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abax55@lp55cs007               BP    0/36/36        1.08     lx-amd64
    gf:app_monitor=1
    gf:app_abaqus=1
    gf:app_abaqusfgs=1
    gf:app_actran=1
    hl:load_avg=38.980000
    hl:load_short=38.550000
    hl:load_medium=38.980000
    hl:load_long=39.030000
```

command

```
 for i in `sed -n '/abax55@lp55cs/p' file.txt  |awk '{print $1}'`; do sed -n "/$i/,+5p" file.txt  | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n  -e '1p' -e '$p' | perl -pne "s/\n/-/"| sed 's/-$/\n/g'; done
```

output

```
abax55@lp55cs008-hl:load_avg=38.980000
abax55@lp55cs009-hl:load_avg=38.980000
abax55@lp55cs007-hl:load_avg=38.980000
```

Comment: @Nayak Can You vote for answer

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `grep` I would use `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %values = do { local $/; <> } =~ m/(\w+\@\w+).*?hl:load_avg=([\d\.]+)/gms; 

print Dumper \%values; 

print $values{'abax55@lp55cs008'}
```

I can probably refine it if you're able to give a more specific record format. But you can parse the whole stanza into a block easily enough, because each new 'block' has no whitespace at the start (it's even easier if there's a clear delimiter between the records, such as a blank line, but without seeing your output I can't tell what that would be).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $current_host = ''; 
my %values; 

#<> reads stdin or files specified on command line.
#if that doesn't work for you, you can "open" a specific file, or 
#use qx() or backticks to run a a command. 
while ( <> ) {
   #match a regex and capture the result if it's valid. 
   if ( m/^(\w+\@\w+)/ ) { $current_host = $1 }; 

   #lines that start with whitespace are the values. 
   if ( m/^\s+(\w+:\w+)=([\d\.]+)/ ) {
      #$1 and $2 are captured via the brackets
      $values{$current_host}{$1} = $2; 
   }
}

#for debug:
print Dumper \%values;

#to print a specific key:

my $target_key = 'hl:load_avg'; 

foreach my $host ( sort keys %values ) {
   print "$host - $target_key=",$values{$host}{$target_key},"\n";
}
```